# Pass a template literal into props as an expression and not a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, css-modules

So I'm trying to use the classnames package to conditionally set classNames for my component but the argument needs to be an expression rather than a string, otherwise it parses it incorrectly.

Here's the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import cx from 'classnames';

import styles from './imagery.module.scss';

export class Imagery extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      sizer: `styles.${props.size.toLowerCase()}`
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Img
          className={cx([this.state.sizer], {
            [styles.firstImage]: this.props.firstImage,
          })}
          fluid={this.props.image}
        />
        {this.props.caption ? (
          <p className={styles.caption}>{this.props.caption}</p>
        ) : (
          false
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Imagery;
```

I'm using CSS Modules in Gatsby.js to essentially go into my "styles" scss module file and find the class according to the expression. Instead it has returned a literal string as opposed to an expression I need to place in className. I've tried assigning a variable inside the `render()` method and then append that value to `styles` but the props can't access it apparently.

Is there a workaround to what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: `sizer: styles[props.size.toLowerCase()]` doesn't work?

Comment: yep, if the prop is dynamic you have to use styles['property']

Comment: hm it only returns undefined unfortunately?

Comment: Works for me. I've created a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-browser-3nu3p  I think there might be something wrong with your scss file or your props.size value.  `props.size=someclass` should correspond to a class style in your scss file: `.someclass { color: red }`